# eventhough i change the environmental variables and classpath, while running sqlite jdbc program i get the error stating no class definition doun

Tags: sqlitejdbc

im running a jdbc program on Sqlite. though i change the environmental variables or define the classpath of the jar file sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar, i get an error stating ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC... how to rectify it?
my code is`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Sample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
      // create a database connection
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

      statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
      statement.executeUpdate("create table person (id integer, name string)");
      statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(1, 'leo')");
      statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(2, 'yui')");
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from person");
      while(rs.next())
      {
        // read the result set
        System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
        System.out.println("id = " + rs.getInt("id"));
      }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      // if the error message is "out of memory", 
      // it probably means no database file is found
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if(connection != null)
          connection.close();
      }
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
        // connection close failed.
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

my jar file is sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
my class path is D:\jdk1.6.0_45\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
my environmental variable is also the same
what should i do?
help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem...
the class path should be like 
`javac Sample.java

java -classpath "D:\jdk1.6.0_45\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar";. Sample`

the problem is solved:)